# set and get a property of type ClassB from ClassA

Tags: java, oop, tostring

I want to have a `setter and getter` for root word by passing and returning an object of type `Word`:

```
class Master {
    Word word = new Word();

    word.setName("eating");
    word.setRootWord(new Word("eat"));

    System.out.println(word.getRootWord().toString());
}


class Word {
    private String name;
    private Word rootWord, synonyms, antonyms;

    public Word () {

    }

    public Word (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public getName () {
        return this.name;
    }

    public setRootWord (Word rootWord) {
        this.rootWord = rootWord;
    }

    public getRootWord () {
        return this.rootWord;
    }
}
```

What gets printed is something like `Word@42a57993`

How can I get `eat` printed on the screen? or a better way of doing this?

Comment: Change  System.out.println(word.getRootWord().toString()); to  System.out.println(word.getRootWord().getName());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is in this line:

```
System.out.println(word.getRootWord().toString());
```

Switch it to:

```
System.out.println(word.getRootWord().getName());
```

Or, as other option, you can override your `toString()` method for a word class, something like this:

```
class Word {
     public override String toString(){
        return this.getName();
     }
}
```

`Word@42a57993` is a class name for your object, and this is a default implementation of a `toString` method in Java as the compiler and `object` class doesn't know anything about the object except the type of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `toString` method of the object class

Answer (score 0):

To stop that rather arbitrary text from being printed, you could override `java.lang.Object#toString()` for your class `Word`.

`toString()` is used by Java to output a string representation of the object. It doesn't have to be a true *serialisation* in the sense that the mapping should be unique, but just an adequate textural representation. Many debuggers will call this method to display an object's state as a tooltip.

To print `eat`, make a call to `word.getRootWord().getName()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
System.out.println(word.getRootWord().getName());
```